# Get data from a json file into Angular ts

Tags: json, angular

Is there any way to get data from a JSON file to angular typescript file in order to use in web pages?

```
 this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:81/CO226/project/loginResult.json').subscribe((res: Response)=>{
     
   
    });
```

this is what I tried.

Comment: You could setup a json server, then give it to angular to consume it. Check this https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server

Answer (score 0):

JSON file could be saved to assets directory inside your project and can be accessed through the following code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TempJsonService {
  jsonUrl = 'assets/file.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getJson(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.jsonUrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: jsonUrl = 'localhost:81/file.json' is it ok?  becase my json file should be in xampp htdocs

Comment: you could have JSON file in the angular project.